# Is ATSAM4S4A supported by ATMEL ICE debugger?

Tags: microcontroller, microchip, atmel, atmel-ice

I have a huge confusion on whether or not this MCU(ATSAM4s4AA-AU) is supported by the ATMEL ICE debugger.

1. First, I checked the official website for [ATSAM4S4A](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/ATSAM4S4A#document-table) and when I got to the "Emulators and Debuggers" section, only the J32 Debug probe was shown.
   [image]
2. Then I checked the IDE section and only Atmel Studio was shown as recommended IDE which is paradoxical since J32 debug port only works with MPLAB according to [this document](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Microchip%20PDFs/J-32_Debug_Probe.pdf).
3. Then I checked an [existing project](http://www.mwmw.ca/index.html) that used Atmel ICE as a debugger using ATSAM4S16BA-AU-ND

This leads me to an assumption that ATMEL ICE would probably work since its documentation says that it works with "all SAM ARM Cortex-M based MCUs on both SWD and JTAG interfaces". However, I am still not 100% sure since I would not expect Microchip to make a mistake excluding ATMEL ICE from the official website link on ATSAM4S4.

Comment: Remember that Atmel and Microchip (who make MPLAB) used to be competitors until Microchip bought Atmel not too long ago. Compatibility between Atmel-branded stuff and Microchip-branded stuff might be poor, and documentation particularly lacking, for at least a few years.

Comment: I'm guessing this is an error from Microchip. As they only list Microchip Studio and ARM GCC compiler, instead of MPLAB X and XC32, I would have been expecting only the Atmel debugger to be compatible as well. It's a very strange combination if the only supported SW tools are the Atmel based ones, but the only HW is Microchip. To be sure before spending any money, I'd ask the Microchip support.